# Google Map not showing users location

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have a google map which i am trying to get to show the users location, if i add the latitude and Longitude its fine, but when i try and get the location dynamically it doesn't show the map.

This works

```
       function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
      zoom: 12
    });
```

But this doesn't

```
     function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
      zoom: 13
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  an access to navigator.geolocation

```
function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 12 });
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        map.setCenter(pos);
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, but dream weaver shows an error on the line var map